# Get the value of an EditText view within a custom dialog box

Tags: android

I have a button that when pressed opens a custom dialog box. The dialog box displays an EditText view. When the user presses the submit button I would like to fetch the value they entered and send it to my server.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) item.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        class CustomOnClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
            int mClientNumber;
            int mRecordNumber;
            String mNotes;
            public CustomOnClickListener( int clientNumber, int recordNumber, String notes ) {
                mClientNumber = clientNumber;
                mRecordNumber = recordNumber;
                mNotes = notes;
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                // This is where I need the notes field
                Log.i("notes", mNotes);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View entryView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_form_layout,null);
            EditText mNotes = (EditText) entryView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_note);
            // ---------------------- Show Dialog Form ----------------------
            builder.setTitle(R.string.entry_form_title);
            builder.setView(entryView)
                .setPositiveButton("Submit", new CustomOnClickListener(mItem.clientNumber, medicine.getRecordNumber(), "im stuck" ))
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
            builder.create();
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

I can get a reference to the notes field but it does not reflect the changes that are made to it. I attempted to also implement a change listener but ran into the issue of not being able to fetch the response and pass it back into the dialog setPositiveButton call.

```
mNotes.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        Log.i("This works", s.toString());
        // how do I get this value to the dialog positive button?
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
});
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a String variable in the class, i.e. String note = "";

Then, set a onClickListener on the positive button and fetch the text from the EditText. I am not sure why are you using a Custom onClickListener

```
.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        note = mNotes.getText();
                      }
});
```

This should do the trick.